# Is it possible to install older version of Spring Roo in STS?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-roo

I'm using STS to work on an old project that uses Spring Roo. I installed Roo from the STS dashboard and that seemed to work fine, but since the current version of Roo is higher than the one used on the project, it updated my pom.xml and other things for the new version. I'd rather stick with the older version of Roo since this code has been around for a while and I don't want to potentially break things by introducing a new version. Is there a way for me to install an older version (1.2.4.RELEASE) into STS?

Comment: Download older version, unpack it, point sts to it, use it.

Comment: @Aleksandr M Any idea where I can find a download to the older versions of roo? The latest I see is 1.2.5 here https://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/

Comment: There used to be download page for roo archives, but it seems that it is no longer available. :( Found this - http://jenv.mvnsearch.org/candidate/show.action?id=20.